# Deserializing unknown Go's gob blob

Tags: go, serialization, reflection, gob, reflect

I have gobs of unknown type. Is there way to print it to view inside?

There might be `gob.Debug` but it is not available for me
https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/debug.go

Googling advices to use `DecodeValue` but it requires initialised `reflect.Value` 
If I get unknown gob blob then I can't pass initialized value on unknown type

https://play.golang.org/p/OWxX1kPJ6Qa

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)


func encode1() []byte {

    x := "123"

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
    err := enc.Encode(x)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return buf.Bytes()

}

func decode1(b1 []byte) {
    var x string
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(b1))
    err := dec.Decode(&x)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x)
}

func decode2(b1 []byte) {
//  var x reflect.Value
    x := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(""))
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(b1))
    err := dec.DecodeValue(x)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", reflect.Indirect(x))
}

func main() {
    b1 := encode1()
    decode1(b1)
    decode2(b1)
}
```

Comment: This is an important feature if be possible. I have same problem and I don't know why previous data is not decode-able. so, I'm looking to another formats like JSON which causes easily debug-able.

Answer (score 0):

you need to [Register](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Register) your type before encode decoding

> Register records a type, identified by a value for that type, under
>   its internal type name. That name will identify the concrete type of a
>   value sent or received as an interface variable. Only types that will
>   be transferred as implementations of interface values need to be
>   registered. Expecting to be used only during initialization, it panics
>   if the mapping between types and names is not a bijection.

Comment: But I do not have serialized structures. Actually I am looking for tool that will list fields names, types, values. If I use hex viewer then it is possible to guess something. So information on Field names and types is there.

Comment: then it's whole another question. all you want is in reflect package

Comment: I have blob encoded with gob. I can't deserialize it in some object or structure to explorer it with reflect.